# Reduce the execution time of VisualStudio solution Build using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfs, msbuild

I have an MSbuild project used for building Visual studio solution.Before  using msbuild it was using devenv.exe for building the solution.It took only 1 hour to build the solution.
After using msbuild it is taking 3 hours

```
<Target Name ="Buildsln">
   <MSBuild  Projects="$(Solutionpath)\Test.sln"  Targets="Rebuild"
             Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32" BuildInParallel="True">
   </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

How can i increase the speed

If i use msbuild.exe from an EXEC task with /m switch it is taking only 1 hour. But i couldn't use that. Please provide any suggestions

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio were you using before? It's very likely that the previous version was also using MSBUILD internally.

Comment: yes it was VS2010. But if you don't mind can you please tell me why it is taking this much time

Comment: I can't know that. It could be anything, and you'll have to find out. Is it CPU time? Disk I/O? Disk fragmentation? You'll have to look and see.

Comment: Turn down the verbosity to minimal. Also i have sometimes found that building in Parallel does not alway help speed. Builds are usually IO bound. Id also clean then build not rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your MSBuild is doing a "Rebuild" instead of a Build.  When you build within VS are you doing a full Rebuild or a regular Build.  Rebuild will typically be much slower and could explain the behavior you're seeing.